# SQL Query : Need to resolve below query logic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two table :

[image]

I want to output like below logic :

If i enter any classcode then i need to all question which related that class code .
I also want a question which is child question of that question .

It is also possible that single classcode match with multiple question  .you can see that classcode 65005  .in this case we consider upper parent question .

If I will pass 42908 then my output like :

[image]

Let me know , if you have any query .

```
   SELECT * FROM QuestionMaster as a INNER JOIN [ClassCodeQuestionMapping] as b ON a.QuestionId = b.QuestionId 
    WHERE b.ClassCode=42908
```

I tried above query but i cant got its child question .

Thanks.

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Comment: @Amit Bisht ,i am new in SQL .So i have no idea how to get that output .

Comment: Start small, how would you select the question ids for a given classcode? Then we can think about pulling out the questions that match the question ids.

Comment: If someone gives you the query, then you won't leave very much.  Could you try something and then share that with us?

Comment: above query gave me classcode and related question . I need to something recursive data .

Comment: Google for "SQL Server recursive hierarchical query"

Answer (score 0):

Positing a worst answer but don't have sql editor to test or write query, will feel happy if someone downvote it but this may give some hint about the logic

```
Select c.Question From (SELECT a.Question, a.ParentQuestionId
FROM QuestoinTable as a
INNER JOIN QuestoinClassMappingTable as b
ON a.QuestionId = b.QuestionId 
where b.ClassCode = 1234) as c 
INNER JOIN QuestoinTable as d
ON c.ParentQuestionId= d.QuestionId
UNION
Select d.Question From (SELECT a.Question, a.ParentQuestionId
FROM QuestoinTable as a
INNER JOIN QuestoinClassMappingTable as b
ON a.QuestionId = b.QuestionId 
where b.ClassCode = 1234) as c 
INNER JOIN QuestoinTable as d
ON c.ParentQuestionId= d.QuestionId
```